# content query webpart with paging - SharePoint 2013

Tags: content-query-web-part

I would like to use CQWP to display content across sites but I'm facing 2 limitations
1) Show only one column - ( now I know you can add fields to CommonViewFields)
2) Paging
3) Styling it

Looking for something I can re use like [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/imtech-content-query-web-part-v14-exslt/) but it seems it doesn't work for SP 2013

thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using CQWP? Why don't you try content search web part. http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/10/using-content-search-web-part-and.html

Comment: No reason at all.  Having really  looked at content search web part as such. Anytime I start looking at it just didn't get to the point to see the end product. Any resources out there that shows an example of how I can use it instead of CQWP to get the same result?

Answer (score 1):

By using a Content Search Web Part you can customize queries to your catalog. You can then create Item and Control display templates to style and show the data you specify.

Here is a pretty good series to get familiar with the process:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/02/14/how-to-set-up-a-product-centric-web-site-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

MSDN article on display templates:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx

Comment: Thanks Mick.Having looked at CS Web Part it in details as yet. But any real world example regarding what im trying to achieve would be great.

Comment: @naijacoder if you follow the technet blog provided above or Chris blog, i think you can achieve this. Below is one more article link from technet http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/05/23/stage-10-configure-the-query-in-a-content-search-web-part-on-a-catalog-item-page.aspx

Comment: A good place to start is to setup your list as a catalog where you can connect to it from another site. From there you should be able to add the CSWP and filter it to just that catalog. Once you are able to pull back list data you can play with the web part settings and get a feel for the display templates before creating your own.